# Initializing a vector from iterators of a container of a different type

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, language-lawyer

Giving the following code:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    char arr[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<char> vec = { 1,2,3 };

    std::vector<int> vec_one(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
    std::vector<int> vec_two(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

Are the initializations for `vec_one` and `vec_two` undefined, implementation defined or defined according to normal type conversion rules?
What if the `char` and `int` types are swapped?

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote on this question. It clearly explains the problem, provides a [mcve], and is delightfully generic and abstract, when contrasted with the majority of questions that wind up with a [tag:c++] tag.

Comment: @IInspectable: I completely agree. And the current crop of answers (including mine) could be more comprehensive.

Comment: I didn't vote on this one, because while I love the clarity, there is no demonstration of research effort. But I do feel the downvote is unfair.

Comment: @rex: Then again, reaching the point where you construct a container from iterators, implement a [mcve] (that *is* minimal *and* complete), and use the terms *"undefined"*, *"implementation defined"*, and *"(well) defined"* requires (and demonstrates) more research effort, than loads of other questions around here.

Comment: I guess we could reach the point that every question that can be answered by referring to the C++ standard could be closed as not showing research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are all fine, subject to the same rules applying when converting a `char` to an `int` (so no concerns there) and `int` to `char`, which will again be subject to the normal rules: the `int` must be small enough to fit into a `char` if `char` is `signed` (otherwise the behaviour is *undefined*), and well-defined wrap-around behaviour if `char` is `unsigned`.

Comment: So the fact that the copy is buried in a vector init/constructor makes no difference? I assume that is obvious, but that is the only thing distinguishing this question from a generic int<-->char conversion question.

Comment: None whatsoever. I'll tag "language lawyer" hoping that someone posts an answer littered with standard references.

Comment: @rex That was the reason of the question, one of those cases where you're 99% sure about it, but better to be 100%.

Comment: You can initialize a vector with a list this way as well,

Answer (score 4):

This is well defined code in all but one case.  `int` is required to have at least the same size as `char` and be able to store at least what a 16 bit twos compliment integer can store.  So when `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)` the behavior is well defined as you `int` can store every value `char` can .  If `sizeof(char) ==`sizeof(int)`and`char`is an alias to`unsigned char`then you could overflow the`int` which is undefined behavior.

The reverse case also has undefined behavior.  If `char` is an alias to `signed char` and `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)` then you could overflow converting the `int` to a `char` which is signed integer overflow and is undefined behavior.  If `char` is an alias to `unsigned char` though it will never be undefined behavior.

Comment: First sentence is not entirely correct. The signedness of `char` is implementation-defined. Consider a `char` that is unsigned, and an `int` with the same range as `char`, that is signed. That conversion isn't valid (to my knowledge). Also (to my knowledge), an `int` is at least 16 bits wide, incorporated from the C Standard, so the issue is essentially moot.

Comment: Integer truncation is not undefined behavior.  The result of the truncation is very well defined indeed,  The UB term is getting a bit overused, these days.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: Well, true. Still, though, I was referring to the phrase *"can convert [...] without issue"*. (Potential) truncation, however, *is* an issue, you need to be aware of (if `int` were allowed to be the same size as `char`).

Comment: @IInspectable Your correct. I missed that edge case. I've updated the answer and hopefully now it covers it all.